# Selenium - passed the captcha but nothing happened

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

*Sorry for my english*

Sup! I trying to parse one site with reCAPTCHA. The captcha appears when the program click on some button, this is popup that blocking all site functional while captcha is not passed. When captcha passing on default browser(not selenium) - the popup closes automaticaly. Then I tried to pass it with proxy, but nothing happens when the captcha have been passed.

[image: passed captcha]

Thanks for help!

I tried to pass captcha by myself but nothing happen. Tried to remove proxy and pass myself. Tried to create humanlike behavior by sleeping program and remove javascript executions.

Comment: I got that when you insert captcha response, it not checking automatically. What I can do with that?

Comment: how can i submit it without <form>?

Answer (score 0):

Google reCAPTCHA is able to detect ChromeDriver instances or other automized drivers through fingerprinting (for example, TLC fingerprinting). I suggest using [undetected chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver). In general, it is quite easy to detect Selenium.